# Connection of NEO4J TO Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, neo4j, synchronization, connection, ojdbc

I am trying to run

```
call apoc.load.driver('oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver');
```

in neo4j to load oracle driver but i am getting below error

> Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke
>   procedure apoc.load.driver: Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Could not load driver class oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
>   oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver

I have placed the jdbc and apoc in plugins and i am able to apoc.load.driver procedure on command prompt .

Please help me with the issue

Comment: Did you restart the server after the installation ? Can you check that the JDBC jar contains a class `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver` ?

Comment: Hi ,  I resolved that issue . Jar file was not in correct path . Now when i am trying to run  command :CALL apoc.load.jdbc("jdbc:oracle:thin:sys/oracle123@localhost:1521:ORACLE",'select * from artists') YIELD row
CREATE (n:artists {name:row.title}); I am getting this erorr

Comment: Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed: Failed to invoke procedure `apoc.load.jdbc`: Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: JDBC URL is not correct.
A valid URL format is: 'jdbc:neo4j:http://<host>:<port>'

Comment: Please help me with the correct syntax .

Comment: Also , Please let me know if i sync my database with neo4j database using jdbc  .Will i be able to copy data from oracle to neo4j database ?

Comment: Can you tru with something like that : `CALL apoc.load.jdbc("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORACLE",'select * from artists', [], {user:'sys', password:'oracle123'}) YIELD row CREATE (n:artists {name:row.title})`

Comment: getting syntax error : Neo.ClientError.Statement.SyntaxError: Invalid input 'a': expected <init> (line 1, column 1 (offset: 0))
"apoc.load.jdbc("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORACLE",'select * from artists', [], {user:'sys', password:'oracle123'}) YIELD row CREATE (n:artists {name:row.title})"
 ^